# Choose which variable to initialize based on certain condition at c-tor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, c++14, unions

Like if I have this structure:

```
struct S
{
   S(const S &arg) : (arg.bIsDouble ? v1{arg.v1} : v{arg.v}) {}

   bool bIsDouble{false};   

   union {
      vector<int> v;

      double v1;
   };
} ;
```

How can I make the copy constructor to either initialize 'v' or 'v1' based on some condition?

Comment: Do note that prior to C++11 your union is illegal due to having a vector member. I would strongly encourage you to consider `boost::variant` rather than trying to reinvent something that's already developed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just outsource your work to [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
struct S {
    S(const S&) = default;
    boost::variant<double, std::vector<int> > v;
};
```

If you don't want to use Boost, you can read about how to write a discriminated union [here](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-17/eggs.variant---part-i), and then implement your own.

Since you only need two types, that's not too complicated, although it's still very error prone and involves a lot of code:

```
struct DoubleOrVector {
    bool is_double;
    static constexpr std::size_t alignment_value = std::max(alignof(double), alignof(std::vector));

    alignas(alignment_value) char storage[std::max(sizeof(double), sizeof(std::vector))];

    DoubleOrVector(double v)
        : is_double(true)
    {
        new (storage) double(v);
    }

    // similar for vector

    DoubleOrVector(const DoubleOrVector& dov) 
        : is_double(dov.is_double)
    {
        if (is_double) {
            new (storage) double(dov.asDouble());
        }
        else {
            new (storage) std::vector<int>(dov.asVector());
        }
    }

    double& asDouble() { 
        assert(is_double);
        return *reinterpret_cast<double*>(storage);
    }

    std::vector<int>& asVector() { 
        assert(!is_double);
        return *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(storage);
    }

    // plus other functions here
    // remember to explicitly call ~vector() when we need to
};
```

And then we're still defaulting our copy ctor:

```
struct S {
    S(const S&) = default;
    DoubleOrVector v;
};
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using Boost library.

Comment: @FISOCPP Then you can implement yourself, I added a skeleton

Comment: You need to support correct alignment here by adding `alignas()` before `storage` declaration.

Comment: @milleniumbug Like I said, it's complicated and error-prone, I'm not about to reinvent the wheel after linking to two different library implementations of it.

Comment: @Barry so don't.  Replace your array with `std::aligned_storage<std::max(sizeof(...)), std::max(alignof(...))>::type storage;`

Comment: @MooingDuck Alright, alright, now it's aligned correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Constructor initialization list won't help here.

You have to use placement new in the class constructor, and then destroy (by manually calling the destructor) the correct member in the destructor. Also, since you define the destructor, you should define or delete the rest of The Big Five.

Minimal code:

```
struct S
{
    bool bIsDouble{false};

    union {
        vector<int> v;
        double v1;
    };

    S(bool d) : bIsDouble(d)
    {
        if(!bIsDouble)
            new(&v) vector<int>();
        // no need to create or destroy a double, since it is trivial
    }

    ~S()
    {
        if(!bIsDouble)
            v.~vector<int>();
    }

    // the other Big Five members are implicitly deleted
    // so no copying, unless you write it yourself.
};
```

Note that switching between types is harder: if you had used the `vector`, and now want to use `double`, you need to destroy the `vector` first. I recommend to hide the data behind the accessor functions to enforce the invariant.

...or just use `boost::variant`. It's way simpler and less bug-prone.

Comment: But then would implicit default constructor of object 'v' be called? Or no - because it's part of a union?

Comment: If I'm reading the standard correctly, in C++11 both the default and copy constructors of the union will be deleted due to the `vector` member.

Comment: @MarkB "If any non-static data member
of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8),
copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding
member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union." Yep, pretty clear. And `vector` has all of those.